Contractor made a sloppy joint on garage door siding 12 years ago, letting cold air in. How would you fix that?
Title says it all.
We bought a house with a heated attached garage, but the siding around the garage door has a sloppy joint—it's too short. This causes quite a bit of cold air infiltration, especially in the winter at -30 Celsius. How would you go about fixing it? Would silicone or rubber tape work without showing too much, or is there another option you'd recommend?



All suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Those strips that look like they were cut too short and/or wrongly appear to be flexible weather stripping. Can you open up the garage  door and take a picture showing just how this is attached to the building structure? This would provide more information so as to be able to offer better advice then simply trying to patch this up with gobs of caulking.

Exactly, those are flexible weather stripping which are put under pressure against the garage door when it's closed. I just added two pictures in the original post (above) with the door open: front side and back side. Thank you for your comment!

A good polyurethane or silicone caulking would work, although it is not clear from the photo if the repair is to the horizontal or vertical member or both since the vertical also appears to be artfully done.
Since your question is as much about appearance as it is about functionality, if you elect to go the sealant route, use painter's tape on either side of the joint, apply and tool the sealant to suit and then remove the tape.
Update:
The weatherstripping has shrunk over time. This may not be the installer's fault.
Your best solution is to purchase a similar profile weatherstrip that fits the groove, this time compressing the weatherstrip by 5-10% before putting back in place so that it stays tight.

Both members have been botched, unfortunately. Thanks for your comment!

On second look, is the pattern at the back a door panel? Do the horizontal and vertical members flex to put the door panels under tension? If so, you will need a tape solution to handle the constant flex.

You are right: the flexible weather stripping flex to put the door panels under tension (the door panel has the pattern you are talking about). I just added two pictures in the original post to make things clearer :) Thanks again.
